Js code is not fetching form repeater datas
I have a simple html website to make a quotations about tour service.
I have this values
vehicle 1-4 :  - 115
Vehicle 5-12 : 125
...

Guiding 1-4 : 150
Guiding 5-8: 160
...

And a form repeater to add entrances and lunch cost values.
That system makes a calculation like this
(Vehicle price + Guiding price + Common expenses) + (Entrance fees and lunch fees total * number of person)* interest rate.
But when implemented, the form repeater system is not considering form repeater values. What can be the problem?


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#entranceRepeater').repeater();
  $('#lunchRepeater').repeater();
});

function getRepeaterData(selector) {
  const data = [];
  $(selector).find('[data-repeater-item]').each(function() {
    const name = $(this).find('[name$="Name"]').val();
    const fee = parseFloat($(this).find('[name$="Fee"]').val()) || 0;
    if (name && fee) {
      data.push({
        name,
        fee
      });
    }
  });
  return data;
}

function getVehiclePrice(pax) {
  if (pax <= 4) return parseFloat(document.getElementById('vehicle1').value) || 0;
  if (pax <= 12) return parseFloat(document.getElementById('vehicle2').value) || 0;
  if (pax <= 27) return parseFloat(document.getElementById('vehicle3').value) || 0;
  return parseFloat(document.getElementById('vehicle4').value) || 0;
}

function getGuidePrice(pax) {
  if (pax <= 4) return parseFloat(document.getElementById('guide1').value) || 0;
  if (pax <= 8) return parseFloat(document.getElementById('guide2').value) || 0;
  if (pax <= 12) return parseFloat(document.getElementById('guide3').value) || 0;
  if (pax <= 18) return parseFloat(document.getElementById('guide4').value) || 0;
  if (pax <= 25) return parseFloat(document.getElementById('guide5').value) || 0;
  return parseFloat(document.getElementById('guide6').value) || 0;
}

function calculateCosts() {
  const commonExpenses = parseFloat(document.getElementById('commonExpenses').value) || 0;
  const interestRate = (parseFloat(document.getElementById('interestRate').value) || 0) / 100;
  const maxPeople = parseInt(document.getElementById('maxPeople').value) || 1;

  // Correctly fetch entrance fees and lunch data from repeater
  const entranceData = [];
  $('[data-repeater-list="entranceList"] [data-repeater-item]').each(function() {
    const name = $(this).find('input[name="entranceName"]').val();
    const fee = parseFloat($(this).find('input[name="entranceFee"]').val()) || 0;
    if (name && !isNaN(fee)) {
      entranceData.push({
        name,
        fee
      });
    }
  });

  const lunchData = [];
  $('[data-repeater-list="lunchList"] [data-repeater-item]').each(function() {
    const name = $(this).find('input[name="lunchName"]').val();
    const fee = parseFloat($(this).find('input[name="lunchFee"]').val()) || 0;
    if (name && !isNaN(fee)) {
      lunchData.push({
        name,
        fee
      });
    }
  });

  // Debug logs to verify fetched data
  console.log("Entrance Data:", entranceData);
  console.log("Lunch Data:", lunchData);

  // Sum up entrance and lunch fees
  const totalEntranceFees = entranceData.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.fee, 0);
  const totalLunchFees = lunchData.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.fee, 0);

  const resultsContainer = document.getElementById('results');
  resultsContainer.innerHTML = `
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Number of People</th>
                            <th>Total Price</th>
                            <th>Price Per Person</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            `;

  const tbody = resultsContainer.querySelector('tbody');
  for (let pax = 1; pax <= maxPeople; pax++) {
    // Determine the appropriate vehicle and guide price based on pax
    const vehiclePrice = getVehiclePrice(pax);
    const guidePrice = getGuidePrice(pax);

    // Calculate total per-person fees for entrance and lunch
    const perPersonCost = (totalEntranceFees + totalLunchFees) * pax;

    // Calculate the total cost including interest
    const totalCost = (vehiclePrice + guidePrice + commonExpenses + perPersonCost) * (1 + interestRate);
    const pricePerPerson = totalCost / pax;

    // Append the results to the table
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.innerHTML = `<td>${pax}</td><td>${totalCost.toFixed(2)}</td><td>${pricePerPerson.toFixed(2)}</td>`;
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  }
}
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
}

.section {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

input[type="number"],
input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.repeater-item {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}

.remove-btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.repeater/jquery.repeater.min.js"></script>
<h1>Calculation System</h1>

<!-- Vehicle Prices -->
<div class="section">
  <h2>Vehicle Prices</h2>
  <label>Vehicle for 1-4 Pax:</label>
  <input type="number" id="vehicle1" placeholder="Enter price">
  <label>Vehicle for 5-12 Pax:</label>
  <input type="number" id="vehicle2" placeholder="Enter price">
  <label>Vehicle for 13-27 Pax:</label>
  <input type="number" id="vehicle3" placeholder="Enter price">
  <label>Vehicle for 28-40 Pax:</label>
  <input type="number" id="vehicle4" placeholder="Enter price">
</div>

<!-- Guiding Prices -->
<div class="section">
  <h2>Guiding Prices</h2>
  <label>Guiding for 1-4 Pax:</label>
  <input type="number" id="guide1" placeholder="Enter price">
  <label>Guiding for 5-8 Pax:</label>
  <input type="number" id="guide2" placeholder="Enter price">
  <label>Guiding for 9-12 Pax:</label>
  <input type="number" id="guide3" placeholder="Enter price">
  <label>Guiding for 13-18 Pax:</label>
  <input type="number" id="guide4" placeholder="Enter price">
  <label>Guiding for 19-25 Pax:</label>
  <input type="number" id="guide5" placeholder="Enter price">
  <label>Guiding for 25-40 Pax:</label>
  <input type="number" id="guide6" placeholder="Enter price">
</div>

<!-- Common Expenses -->
<div class="section">
  <h2>Common Expenses</h2>
  <label>Common Expenses:</label>
  <input type="number" id="commonExpenses" placeholder="Enter amount">
</div>

<!-- Entrance and Lunch Items -->
<div class="section">
  <h2>Entrance Places and Lunch Items</h2>
  <div class="repeater" id="entranceRepeater">
    <h3>Entrance Places</h3>
    <div data-repeater-list="entranceList">
      <div data-repeater-item class="repeater-item">
        <label>Entrance Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="entranceName" placeholder="Enter name">
        <label>Entrance Fee (per person):</label>
        <input type="number" name="entranceFee" placeholder="Enter fee">
        <button data-repeater-delete class="remove-btn">Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button data-repeater-create>Add Entrance</button>
  </div>

  <div class="repeater" id="lunchRepeater">
    <h3>Lunch Items</h3>
    <div data-repeater-list="lunchList">
      <div data-repeater-item class="repeater-item">
        <label>Lunch Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lunchName" placeholder="Enter name">
        <label>Lunch Fee (per person):</label>
        <input type="number" name="lunchFee" placeholder="Enter fee">
        <button data-repeater-delete class="remove-btn">Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button data-repeater-create>Add Lunch</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Interest Rate and People Count -->
<div class="section">
  <h2>Interest Rate and People Count</h2>
  <label>Interest Rate (%):</label>
  <input type="number" id="interestRate" placeholder="Enter percentage">
  <label>Maximum Number of People:</label>
  <input type="number" id="maxPeople" placeholder="Enter maximum number of people">
</div>

<!-- Results -->
<div class="section">
  <button onclick="calculateCosts()">Calculate Costs</button>
  <div id="results"></div>
</div>




Please change the snippet I made you into a [mcve] and show how to reproduce the error and explain expected result

When you add a value to entrance fee side a name and a number you will see that is not calculating. ı am sorry may be i couldn ask well my question

"I have this values...": how are these values incorporated into the code? Are they a string, array, object...?

It's because jquery-repeater modifies the name attribute of your form elements (the first one has name="entranceList[0][entranceName]") so you never find the entranceName input.  See "rewritten name attributes" here.  I suggest you assign a class to those inputs and use that to find them.
